# How to read NETCDF files in julia?

Tags: julia, netcdf

I am trying to open a netcdf file but I'm getting the following error:

```
error compiling #Dataset#19: error compiling nc_open: could not load library "/Users/kanwal/.julia/conda/3/lib/libnetcdf.dylib"
dlopen(/Users/kanwal/.julia/conda/3/lib/libnetcdf.dylib, 1): image not found

Stacktrace:
 [1] Type at /Users/kanwal/.julia/packages/NCDatasets/uW2kc/src/NCDatasets.jl:482 [inlined] (repeats 2 times)
 [2] top-level scope at In[27]:1
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of a Julia packages ([NCDatasets.jl](https://github.com/Alexander-Barth/NCDatasets.jl) & [NetCDF.jl](https://github.com/JuliaGeo/NetCDF.jl))  which work extremely well for this purpose. I've been using NCDatasets.jl, and the documentation is quite detailed as to this packages' supported operations.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `libnetcdf` to your `Conda` environment manually:

```
using Pkg
pkg"add Conda"
Conda.runconda(`install -c anaconda libnetcdf`)
```

Comment: This should no longer be necessary as NCDatasets.jl & NetCDF.jl use the NetCDF library from https://github.com/JuliaPackaging/Yggdrasil .